# Parsing HTML with JSoup in Fragment

Tags: android, jsoup

While parsing a HTML Website into Android Studio (Fragment) using JSoup, Android Studio doesn`t show an error and the AVD starts. But, I can`t change the text of a TextView.
Setting the text of a TextView doesn`t work.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Website().execute();

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }


    }

    // Title AsyncTask
    private class Website extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String title;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/").get();
                // Get the html document title
                title = doc.title();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            // Set title into TextView
            TextView txttitle = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
            txttitle.setText(title);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
```

I want to display the title of the Website in the TextView "titletxt".

Comment: Have you debugged the app step by step to isolate the problem? Is it that Jsoup fails to read the website? Is it that there's no `title` element on the page? Is it that you get a title, but `txttitle` is null and the application crashes? Or is all this code in an `Adapter` and somehow you just can't update the `TextView` from the `Adapter` as you have e.g. forgotten to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Hi Markus, thx for your response. None of this is the case. The title should be "Facebook" in the example. Not sure if it`s because of the fragment. Do i need to change anything in my androidmanifest?

Comment: Do you even know if Jsoup manages to fetch the data?

Comment: Seems like there is an error: "2019-04-09 11:52:46.818 1861-1883/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module", but I really don`t know what it means.

Comment: 2019-04-09 12:02:22.818 1861-3039/system_process E/SupplicantStaIfaceHal: ISupplicantStaIface.setPowerSave failed: {.code = FAILURE_UNKNOWN, .debugMessage = }
2019-04-09 12:02:42.924 1861-1883/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-04-09 12:02:42.928 1769-1769/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-04-09 12:02:42.928 1769-1769/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument#

Comment: Ah, you are running on QEMU. Well, I'd check the basic things first, like is there even internet access and update the question with more details as now it's quite difficult for anyone to tell where the problem is. Could a missing internet permission in your app, could be QEMU problem, could be a problem in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Better if you execute the Task on `onViewCreated`
Of fragment 
The code is working fine. Or set a user agent to jsoup.That may help

Comment: Hi, I execute the task in onVieCreated, but it is still not working. In the Logcat i get the following errors: "GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!" and "Couldn't load memtrack module"

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/").get(); title = doc.select("title").text(); //try this one